# Threading serializable operations in python is slower than running them sequentially

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am attempting to have two long running operations run simultaneously in python.  They both operate on the same data set, but do not modify it.  I have found that a threaded implementation runs slower than simply running them one after the other.

I have created a simplified example to show what I am experiencing.

Running this code, and commenting line 46 (causing it to perform the operation threaded), results in a runtime on my machine of around 1:01 (minute:seconds).  I see two CPUs run at around 50% for the full run time.

Commenting out line 47 (causing sequential calculations) results in a runtime of around 35 seconds, with 1 CPU being pegged at 100% for the full runtime.
Both runs result in the both full calculations being completed.

```
from datetime import datetime
import threading


class num:
    def __init__(self):
        self._num = 0

    def increment(self):
        self._num += 1

    def getValue(self):
        return self._num

class incrementNumber(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._number = number
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.incrementProcess()

    def incrementProcess(self):
        for i in range(50000000):
            self._number.increment()


def runThreaded(x, y):
    x.start()
    y.start()
    x.join()
    y.join()

def runNonThreaded(x, y):
    x.incrementProcess()
    y.incrementProcess()

def main():
    t = datetime.now()

    x = num()
    y = num()
    incrementX = incrementNumber(x)
    incrementY = incrementNumber(y)

    runThreaded(incrementX, incrementY)
    #runNonThreaded(incrementX, incrementY)


    print x.getValue(), y.getValue()
    print datetime.now() - t


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPython has a so-called [Global Interpreter Lock](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf), which means that only one Python statement can run at a time even when multithreading. You might want to look into [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html), which avoids this constraint.

The GIL means that Python multithreading is only useful for I/O-bound operations, other things that wait for stuff to happen, or if you're calling a C extension that releases the GIL while doing work.

Comment: I don't use Python anyway, but I don't see why that miserable mutex is necessary anyway.  Couldn't Python store a context object or pointer thereto in thread-local storage, ot find some other way for each thread to have its very own interpreter instance?

Comment: To repeat myself from below: There are [implementations of Python](http://wiki.python.org/jython/WhyJython) without a GIL. As to 'each thread having its very own interpreter instance' - that's what ``multiprocessing`` (mentioned in the answer) does.

Comment: Some developers do not want to share their 5GB data buffer with another process!  Anywy, as you say, it seems that there are indeed GILless pythons, so my answer is misleading, if not actually wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid it is wrong - Python is the language, which doesn't specify anything. CPython has a GIL, but that's an implementation detail, not a part of the language itself, so you can't say 'Python is rubbish at multi-threading'. It's CPython with the issue. While it's true a lot of people think of them as synonymous, they are not.